# Draw rect causing errors, can't reference myview

Tags: ios, drawrect, self

Here is my code. I'm trying to access the frame of my view.
First i nslog self, to make sure the view is allocated, and then i try to nslog the frame of my view, it returns null. 
Code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"%@",self);
    CGRect frameads = self.frame;
    NSLog(@"%@",frameads);
}
```

Compiler output:

```
2012-07-18 11:41:59.808 animation[74551:f803] <MyView: 0x68568e0; frame = (0 37; 320 321); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6856a50>>
2012-07-18 11:41:59.808 animation[74551:f803] (null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frame` is a struct (`CGRect`) so wont be logged using %@, use

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you!!
now it shows:
2012-07-18 11:50:53.480 animation[74608:f803] {{0, 37}, {320, 321}}